# ionic 3 [object object] not able to parse data

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Actually I'm getting below data from the server.

```
{
"status": 1,
"message": "Product Detail",
"data": {
    "product": {
        "product_id": "87",
        "product_name": "Decide A4-12",
        "product_price": "Rs. 199.00",
        "product_shortdescription": "FREE Delivery Portrait",
        "product_description": "FREE Delivery\r\nSize : A4\r\nPaper Quality : 170 gsm\r\nPackage ",
        "product_small_image": "https:\\xxxxxx\/p\/o\/pos_02_2.jpg",
        "product_detail_image": "https:\\xxxxxx\/p\/o\/pos_02_2.jpg",
        "gallery": [{
            "gallery_url": "https:\\xxxxxx\/p\/o\/pos_02_2.jpg"
        }],
        "is_in_stock": 1
    },
    "reviews": {
        "count": 0,
        "review": []
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using `POST` method with `Promise` for get data. In **network** I got JSON and also validated by **JSONLint**.

But if want to print in console then it saw **[object Object]**.

Actually question is how to parse data of dictionary.

I want to display image from *`product_detail_image`*

my **.ts** file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ApiProvider, APIName } from '../../providers/api/api';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-productdetail',
  templateUrl: 'productdetail.html',
})
export class ProductdetailPage {

  dicProductDetail: any

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
     public apiProvider: ApiProvider) {       
     this.wsForGetProductDetail(navParams.get("productID"))
  }

  wsForGetProductDetail(productID: String){
    this.apiProvider.wsPost(APIName.getProductDetailApi, "product_id="+productID).then( responseData => {      
       this.dicProductDetail = responseData
       console.log("DATA ==> " + this.dicProductDetail["product"])
    }, (err) => {
       alert(err)
    });
  }
}
```

> Where **responseData = response["data"]** so I don't need to write *["data"]* when I will fetch `product_detail_image`.

my **.html** file

```
<ion-content padding >
  <img [src]="dicProductDetail[product].product_detail_image">
</ion-content>
```

But image not get display.

Got below error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Anybody can guide me on right direction where I'm going to wrong ?

**EDITED: for more clear about *wsPost()***

```
wsPost(strAPIName, params){
    console.log("params : " + JSON.stringify(params))
    console.log("Api : " + this.baseURL+strAPIName)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.baseURL+strAPIName, params, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
      })
      .subscribe(response => {
        if(response["status"] == 1) {          
          resolve(response["data"])
        }
        else if(response["status"] == 2) {          
          alert(response["message"])  
        }
        else {
          alert("Something is going wrong please try again")  
        }
      }, (err) => {
        alert("Error: " + err.message)
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: *"Where responseData = response["data"]"* ... where exactly are you doing this? It's not anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: @JJJ Ok I will update my code

Comment: Also, [object Object] is because of the string concatenation. Do `console.log(this.dicProductDetail.product)` to see the actual object.

Comment: @JJJ - NO getting same [object Object], BTW I updated for your first comment

Comment: write `console.log(responseData)` in your then response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840008/cannot-read-property-of-xxx-of-undefined is your issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property of 'xxx' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840008/cannot-read-property-of-xxx-of-undefined)

Comment: view is loaded before data fetch

Comment: That's not a valid Json. Where the brackets are opened?

Comment: @Melchia - its valid I just edited it thats why.

Comment: "product_small_image": "https:\xxxxxx\/p\/o\/pos_02_2.jpg"
            }],",

Comment: Where is the opening of the bracket?

Comment: Post the full JSON if you want real help.

Comment: can you give me output of console.log(this.dicProductDetail); ?

Comment: @Melchia and "@dgpoo" plz check, I just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks **@Suraj Rao** for your comment.

You are right, It happens because page is loaded before get data from server.

So your suggested link did not work for me but I found solution from below link.

[load data in the view before loading it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705736/load-data-in-the-view-before-loading-it)

I used **`ngIf`** like below.

```
<ion-content padding >
<div *ngIf="dicProductDetail">
    <img [src]="dicProductDetail['product'].product_detail_image">
</div>
```

And my problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<ion-content padding >
  <img [src]="dicProductDetail['data'].product.product_detail_image">
</ion-content>
```

or try this in you controller

```
this.dicProductDetail = responseData.data
```

if you do the above one, you don't need to change in your html side

Comment: got ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

Did u try

console.log(JSON.stringify(data.product_detail_image))